# How to use Bundle in kotlin multiplatform or any alternative for it

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, bundle, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a project to use kotlin multiplatform to use for our business logic so I was converting our java code to kotlin. But I cannot call Bundle anymore and i cannot import android.os.bundle too.
Any alternative for Bundle that I can use in Kotlin Multiplatform?

Java

```
public interface RequestCallback {
    void receivedCallbackFromRequest(BaseRequest request, Bundle result)
}
```

converted to Kotlin

```
interface RequestCallback {
    fun receivedCallbackFromRequest(request: BaseRequest , result: Bundle)
}
```

Comment: A Bundle is basically a `MutableMap<String, String>` where functions like `getInt()` are getting the String value from the map and converting it to an Int.

Comment: Sure there are alternative ways but why do you need them?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking I'd leave `Bundle`s out of the **KMP** picture, since they are mostly used on the **View** layer and if you try to share View layer logic between platforms you'll bump into all sorts of these kind of issues.
If you're using the `Bundle` on non-view layers also, I'd say create a simple `Map<String, String>` and map that to a `Bundle` on your Android view layer.

If you would like to remain with the `android.os.Bundle`, I'd go with creating a multiplatform abstraction for it:

```
expect class Bundle {
    fun putInt(int: Integer)
    ....
}
```

```
actual typealias Bundle = android.os.Bundle
```

Now you still need to define it for your other platforms, depending on your target.

And again, the more you get into platform specific layers the harder your life will get, especially with the **View layer**.
You can get away with sharing the `ViewModel` though and it still gives a nice shared code percentage. See an [example here](https://github.com/halcyonmobile/MultiplatformPlayground/blob/master/common/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/halcyonmobile/multiplatformplayground/viewmodel/HomeViewModel.kt)